# Best method to create large graph that can be panned and scaled with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I have a request form a client and am looking for advice on the best procedure. I believe that HTML 5 can help however I'm not too experience in the more advanced features of HTML 5 to come to a conclusion.

Basically my client is looking to have a universe which in effect really is just a large graph. Plotted within the universe are elements that are added by users. This amount will increase over time. Hence the graph will increase in dimensions. The idea is to see the universe as a whole with small dots representing elements. Then a user can zoom in and/or pan the universe to discover different elements. Clicking an element bring up a dialog and more information can be gained. Zooming can happen in real time or is it acceptable to click a region and it gets bigger.

My assumption is that the best way to go about this is to use HTML 5 and Javascript. However as stated I'm new to HTML 5 and its limitations.

It would be nice if it could be light-weight and accessible on multiple devices (mobile, tables, etc).

Is HTML the solution here? What would be the best practice? Any suggestions?

Comment: how is google maps implemented?

Comment: I'm looking for a simple solution. Like having a large html page that can be zoomed and panned but not with scroll bars.

Comment: I have attempted to indirectly answer your question here whether HTML is the solution. Since google has gone this route and evaluated various solutions to a problem which is a super-set of yours, you can rely on their results and take their maps as an example.

Comment: My understanding of how maps works is by having tiles align within a div and manipulates with javascript. I think this is would be too involved and the client will not be prepared to fund such work. My current thought is to use an iframe. Just display one big html page within the iframe and manipulates with JS. Sure this will one day be slow if the size in always increasing but that can be fixed if/when the website is successful and has many elements to display. I suppose a div with overflow hidden is not much different to an iframe....

Answer (score 0):

A while back I built something very similar by integrating with Google Maps. I pulled addresses from my database, converted using a Geocode tool, then with PHP/Javascript combination I input the data into Google Maps (just using a simple `foreach` loop) and stuck the code on my site. In all, it was pretty simple since Google handles most the application.

The hardest part, IMO, was validating the addresses and converting them to Geocode.

If you want to take this route, here are some helpful links:

GOOGLE MAPS INTEGRATION DOCUMENTATION (pretty much contains everything you'll need to know)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

GEOCODING WITH GOOGLE (Limits you to 2500 hits per day)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

And the rest I'd search here in stackoverflow.

Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but this has nothing to do with google maps or geocoding... It's just a large graph with dots on it. I need to be able to zoom and pan. Simplest way possible.

Comment: Ah ok, misunderstood I guess, sorry about that. Perhaps this stuff might be helpful then: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery (sticking with Google route since they are easy to integrate with) or http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ (great site, I use it to display trends for clients...might have an avenue for you).